# Problems with sign up, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with saving session when doing 'sign up'

'sign up' option makes a new user, it's okay, but I want it to remember the session also. Session works well when 'sign in', but when a new user is created current_user is still empty and I get an error

> undefined method `meetings' for nil:NilClass

```
def month_for_user  
 @meetings = current_user.meetings
end
```

This is my **sessions_controller**

```
def new
end

def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
```

Do i have to add something here? But can I get my new_user through the User model or is there some another solution?

```
  if user
    sign_in user
    redirect_to user
  else
    redirect_to root_url, alert: "Wrong email or password. Please, try again"
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings

  def self.authenticate (email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return user if user != nil && password == user.password
    return nil
  end
end
```

**sessions_helper**

```
def sign_up(user)
  session[:id] = user.id
  self.current_user = user
end

def sign_in(user)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  self.current_user = user
end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
  session[:user_id] = nil
  self.current_user = nil

end

def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end
```

I need to show all the meetings that belong to registered user (current_user)
and this is my **calendar_controller** which works well when I do 'sign in', but not 'sign_up', because current_user is still empty.

```
def month_for_user
  @meetings = current_user.meetings
end
```

I don't know how to tell sessions_controller to make new_user into a current_user. I tried to change **users_controller** :

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    sign_up @user #THAT WAS WHAT I ADDED BUT IT DIDN'T HELP

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save

        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I suggest that the problem occurs because I use sessions_helper and get current_user from the User model, which prevents me from getting a new_user. Can I get a new_user from a User model somehow? Or do I have to change all the logic itself? Please, give me any idea of how and where to make new_user into a current_user. 
Sorry for a lot of code, but I tried to explain as much as possible to make it easier for understanding.
Thank you!

Comment: I changed sign_up method into session[:user_id] = user.id (but i still don't understand why the previous variant isn't right) and i put it under @user.save 
It works! Thank you for all your advise! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating the session before saving the user, it doesn't have and id yet (its created on save). I think you should try something like:
....

```
if @user.save
  ..do your thing..
  sign_up @user
else
  .. another thing..
end
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that until you save the user there is no user.id. If you look at your sessions helper you have sign_up use the following code:

```
session[:id] = user.id
```

However, until you save the user a few lines further down, there is no user.id. You should be setting the session token once the save is successful.

I would strongly recommend reviewing some standard rails authentication as this is fairly boilerplate stuff. No need to [reinvent the wheel](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users).